# Fixed amount of digits after the decimal

Tags: java, numbers, double, decimal

I have many `double` numbers which describes different objects.

For example:

```
 Object A
    double a = 10.12
    double b = 10.1223
    double c = 10.12345

 Object B
    double a = 10.12
    double b = 10.1223
    double c = 10.12345
```

...and I want have fixed amount of digits after decimal, for example Object A must have 5 (five) digits after decimal and Object B must have 2 (two) digits after decimal with rounding up. I want achieve something like this :

```
 Object A
    10.12000
    10.12230
    10.12345

Object B
    10.12
    10.12
    10.12
```

I try `setMinimumFractionDigits(5)` or `setMinimumFractionDigits(2)` and it works but I have many objects and first must have one digit after decimal other need 5 etc. This is big project and is object-oriented.

Any idea how can I achieve this ?

Comment: Please have a read of the following official docs first: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like mentioned in the comment, check out [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).

For you, it would look like the following:

```
// For Object A
DecimalFormat dfForObjA = new DecimalFormat("#.#####");
dfForObjA.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.CEILING);
for (double d : A) {   // Assuming A is already declared and initialized
    System.out.println(dfForObjA.format(d));
}

// For Object B
DecimalFormat dfForObjB = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
dfForObjB.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.CEILING);
for (double d : B) {   // Assuming B is already declared and initialized
    System.out.println(dfForObjB.format(d));
}
```

*Note:* For the for each loop, I'm not too sure how to implement it exactly with your objects since it's unclear what they exactly are or how they're defined.

Answer (score 2):

Please change your code by creating `DecimalFormat` obj and use it for formatting `Double` objects.

```
private static DecimalFormat fiveDigitFormat= new DecimalFormat(".#####");
private static DecimalFormat twoDigitFormat= new DecimalFormat(".##");

fiveDigitFormat.format(objA);
twoDigitFormat.format(objB);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also simply use:

```
double a = 10.12;
double b = 10.1223;
double c = 10.12345;
System.out.println(String.format("%.5f", a));
System.out.println(String.format("%.5f", b));
System.out.println(String.format("%.2f", c));
```

It prints:

```
10.12000
10.12230
10.12
```